# For comprehension - execute futures in order

Tags: scala

If I have the following for comprehension, futures will be executed in order: `f1`, `f2`, `f3`:

```
   val f = for {
      r1 <- f1
      r2 <- f2(r1)
      r3 <- f3(r2)
    } yield r3
```

For this one however, all the futures are started at the same time:

```
  val f = for {
      r1 <- f1
      r2 <- f2
      r3 <- f3
    } yield ...
```

How can I enforce the order?(I want this order of execution `f1`, `f2`, `f3`)

Comment: What are `f1`, `f2`, `f3` in the first case, and in the second case?

Comment: For instance `f1` is   `val f1: Future[Unit] = Future {
    Thread sleep 5
    println(1)
    1
  }` but it think it doesn't matter, I'm just curious of a way of enforcing order among futures, even though they don't depend on the same data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does matter what `f1`, `f2`, `f3` are: a future will start executing a soon as it is created. In your first case, `f2(r1)` must be a *function* returning a future, so the future begins executing when the function is called, which happens when `r1` becomes available.

If the second case is the same (`f2` is a function), then behavior will be the same as the first case, your futures will be executed sequentially, one after the other.

But if you create the futures outside the `for`, and just assign them to variables `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, then by the time you get inside the comprehension, they are *already* running.

Answer (score 2):

`Future` are eager constructs, that is, once created you can not dictate when they get processed. If the `Future` already exists when you attempt to use it in a for-comprehension, you've already lost the ability to sequence it's execution order.

If you want to enforce ordering on a method that accepts `Future` arguments then you'll need to wrap the evaluation in a thunk:

```
def foo(ft: => Future[Thing], f2: => Future[Thing]): Future[Other] = for{
  r1 <- ft
  r2 <- f2
} yield something(r1, r2)
```

If, on the other hand, you want to define the `Future` within a method body, then instead of `val` use a `def`

```
def foo() ={
  def f1 = Future{ code here... }
  def f2 = Future{ code here... }
  for{
    r1 <- f1
    r2 <- f2
  } yield something(r1, r2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Executing futures in for comprehension is default behavior. It is good when few tasks are processed parrallel without any blocking.

But if you want to preserve procecessing order you have to ways:

- Send result of first task to second like in your example
- use `andThen` operator

  ```
  val allposts = mutable.Set[String]()    
  Future {
    session.getRecentPosts
  } andThen {
    posts => allposts ++= posts
  } andThen {
    posts =>
    clearAll()
    for (post <- allposts) render(post)
  }
  ```